# Poor Wireguard Performance using Mobile Data

Tags: networking, ubuntu, vpn, nat

I've setup a Wireguard server (running on Ubuntu server 20.10 (ASRock J4105), plugged directly into the router). I've managed to get it working after some difficulty actually getting access to the internet through the VPN. To get it working I've had to use an MTU of 1150 on all client devices. Otherwise nothing loads.

Connecting to the VPN from my wifi network I get a throughput of around 20Mbps down and 4Mbps up which is about what I get without the VPN (it is slightly faster without which I'd expect).

Now the issue I'm seeing is that if I connect to the VPN via my mobile data connection, throughput drops I get 3Mbps down and 3Mbps up and I can't work out what could be causing the bottleneck.

I've tried setting up Wireguard using a standalone Raspberry Pi 4 8GB model and I get exactly the same results. From what I've read online people are getting significantly higher speeds from their wireguard VPNs using raspberry Pi's than I am on either a Pi or my server. Which I can't work out.

I've looked on my router and I can't see anything that would block the connection. Port Forwarding is all setup to allow connections to the VPN.

Its not the ISP limiting VPN traffic as I've been able to  use Private Internet Access without issues on the Wireguard protocol for a little while now and previously used it on the OpenVPN protocol.

What type of things/settings on the network could be causing a bottleneck?

IPTables - MSS Clamping?

```
   42  2520 TCPMSS     tcp  --  *      *       0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU
```

Comment: Lack of MTU clamping ?

Comment: @davidgo Hi, I think I have MSS clamping on. I've edited the question with the relevant line from my iptables. But to be honest I've not heard of it before trying to work out where wireguard might be being bottlenecked, so not sure its right.